# How to use SchemaSpy with SQLite?

Tags: java, sqlite, schemaspy

How to use SchemaSpy to create an ERD of an SQLite database? I'm trying this with the chinook.db sample database.

Using this command:

```
java -jar schemaspy-6.1.0.jar -t sqlite -db chinook.db -u admin -o .
```

I get this partial output:

```
INFO  - The following profiles are active: default
INFO  - Started Main in 0.937 seconds (JVM running for 1.232)
INFO  - Starting schema analysis
WARN  - Connection Failure
Failed to connect to database URL [jdbc:sqlite:/chinook.db] opening db: '/chinook.db': Read-only file system
INFO  - StackTraces have been omitted, use `-debug` when executing SchemaSpy to see them
```

I don't understand what Read-only is trying to tell me as this is executed in a directory of my own on my Mac.

I've downloaded the latest SQLite JDBC driver and tried this command line:

```
java -jar schemaspy-6.1.0.jar -t sqlite -dp sqlite-jdbc-3.30.1.jar -db chinook.db -u admin -o .
```

And the system responds this way:

```
INFO  - The following profiles are active: default
INFO  - Started Main in 0.706 seconds (JVM running for 0.996)
INFO  - Starting schema analysis
WARN  - Connection Failure
Failed to connect to database URL [jdbc:sqlite:/chinook.db] Failed to create any of 'org.sqlite.JDBC' driver from driverPath 'sqlite-jdbc-3.30.1.jar' with sibling jars no.
Resulting in classpath: empty
There were missing paths in driverPath:
    sqlite-jdbc-3.30.1.jar
Use commandline option '-dp' to specify driver location.
If you need to load sibling jars used '-loadjars'
INFO  - StackTraces have been omitted, use `-debug` when executing SchemaSpy to see them
sd
```

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

The first error read-only probably is because it tries to create a database in root. Path to db is absolut

I don't know exactly which version of SchemaSpy, but `-t sqlite-xerial` has been added for the xerial driver.

And it seems that the `-dp` argument didn't point to the driver or that it wasn't resolved correctly.

But as an example having everything in `/chinook` (schemaspy, xerial JDBC driver, database) and running from that directory the command should look something like

`java -jar schemaspy-6.2.2.jar -dp /chinook/sqlite-jdbc-3.30.1.jar -t sqlite-xerial -db /chinook/chinook.db -sso -s chinook -cat chinook -o implied -o report`

If there's still any issues please create an issue at GitHub.